# Withou onnx, how to convert a pytorch model into a tensorflow model manually?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, exchange-server, onnx

Since ONNX supports limited models, I tried to do this conversion by assigning parameters directly, but the gained tensorflow model failed to show the desired accuracy. Details are described as follows:

1. The source model is Lenet trained on MNIST dataset.
2. I firstly extracted each module and its parameters by model.named_parameters() and save them into a dictionary where the key is the module's name and the value is the parameters
3. Then, I built and initiated a tensorflow model with the same architecture
4. Finally, I assign each layer's parameters of pytroch model to the tensorflow model

However, the accuracy of gained tensorflow model is only about 20%. Thus, my question is that is it possible to convert the pytorch model by this method?. If yes, what's the possible issue causing the bad result? If no, then please kindly explain the reasons.

PS: assume the assignment procedure is right.

Comment: There are small details which make the ops in tensorflow and pytorch not exactly the same (for example padding may be different, epsilons, etc...). This is why there are conversions to/from intermediate representations like onnx or mmdnn which have been carefully tested for consistency. If you want to do this yourself and want to have confidence it will work you will probably want to first design tests for every operation you're going to use to ensure consistency (conv layers, batch norm, activations, data formats, data augmentations, etc...).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I give up to conversion by hand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment by jodag mentioned, there are many differences between operator representations in Tensorflow and PyTorch that might cause discrepancies in your workflow.

We would recommend using the following method:

1. Use the [ONNX exporter in PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_onnxruntime.html) to export the model to the ONNX format.

```
import torch.onnx

# Argument: model is the PyTorch model 
# Argument: dummy_input is a torch tensor

torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "LeNet_model.onnx")
```

2. Use the [onnx-tensorflow backend](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow) to convert the ONNX model to Tensorflow.

```
import onnx

from onnx_tf.backend import prepare

onnx_model = onnx.load("LeNet_model.onnx")  # load onnx model
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)  # prepare tf representation
tf_rep.export_graph("LeNet_model.pb")  # export the model
```

Comment: Many thanks! The pytorch should include the onnx module (:-. I'll give a try.

Comment: The above mentioned conversion runs without errors. However when I try to convert the model further to tflite, I get `import_tensorflow.cc:2619] Check failed: status.ok() Unexpected value for attribute 'data_format'. Expected 'NHWC'
Fatal Python error: Aborted`

shouldn't this be fixed after calling `prepare`? Can you tell me what exact version of TF, pytorch and ONNX you were using?